# ASP.NET WebForms - Execute JavaScript validation and Validation Control at the same time

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

In the application I'm developing, I using both the Validation controls provided by ASP.NET Web Forms and for certain parts of the form I'm using JavaScript.

Both aspects of the validation works as it should, however, when I click on the Submit button the ASP.NET validation comes first, then follows my custom validation made in JavaScript. As a result, when the form is incomplete and submitted, only the ASP.NET validation errors show, and when those errors are corrected and the form is submitted, then my validation errors are shown.

What I want is that when a user clicks on the Submit button, both the ASP.NET validation and my JavaScript validation occur simultaneously so that users can see all the errors at once.

```
<form id="StudentLSFApplication" runat="server" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <!--other html code-->
    <asp:Button ID="SaveLSFApplication" runat="server" Text="Save Application" OnClick="saveApplication"
            ValidationGroup="AllValidation" />
</form>

<script>
    function validateForm() {
        //my validation
    }
</script>
```

As you can see from my sample code, I have the JavaScript function `validateForm()` being called in an `onsubmit` event, and `Button` control is part of the `AllValidation` validation group. At the moment, on form submit the `AllValidation` occurs first, and when that is okay, then `validateForm()` occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the CustomValidator. You can use it like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateFormElement(sender, args) {
            if (args.Value == "waarde") {
                args.IsValid = true;
            } else {
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
        }
    </script>

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="myValidation"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Input error" ValidationGroup="myValidation" ClientValidationFunction="validateFormElement" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:CustomValidator>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="myValidation" />
```

And you can still use all the other validators. No need to cram every validation you want into that one javascript function.

Comment: It's recommend to use other validators provided by Microsoft or, for more complexity, a `CustomValidator` for each kind of validation / control. The ASP.NET validators are great, because they validate with JavaScript **and with C# (code behind)**. JavaScript can be bypassed, so you should add a code behind event on the `CustomValidator` and program the validation not just on JavaScript, but even on C#. A `CustomValidator` should point only on one control, but it can share the same functions accross other validators. `ControlToValidate` should be set.

Comment: The above example was for a single control in a form, not the complete validation in one function. Edited the answer a bit to make that more clear. But if you want to do more complex clientside validation over multiple controls like 'if CheckBox1 is checked then TextBox1 must contain data' then you can leave out the ControlToValidate to make sure the CustomValidator fires. And still always do validation in code behind like modiX suggests.