# JQuery checkbox required validation works only first time

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, validation, checkbox

I am having a weird issue while placing a validation for checkbox. it is working fine on first time when I didn't check the checkbox and hit submit button but if I hit the button again it won't check validation rule and gives an error instead.

```
CONTROL:
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="IAgreedCheckBox" placeholder="Required Field"/>
```

### VALIDATION:

```
$('form').validate({
            rules: {

                '<%=IAgreedCheckBox.UniqueID%>': {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                document.getElementById("ValidEntry").value = "TRUE";
                return true;
            }
        })
```

### ERROR ON 2nd TIME SUBMIT BUTTON CLICK:

```
Unhandled exception at line 2, column 12711 in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: label[for='ctl00$body$IAgreedCheckBox'], label[for='ctl00$body$IAgreedCheckBox'] *, #ctl00$body$IAgreedCheckBox-error
```

Comment: Tried on Chrome and IE same results.

Comment: You should use the validators supplied by dotnet. See my answer to a similar question to get you started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767774/asp-net-webforms-execute-javascript-validation-and-validation-control-at-the-s/38777050?noredirect=1#comment64926373_38777050